# Selecting order by matches in second table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am having a little trouble trying select ids of items ordered by the number of times they have been voted upon.
The votes are held in a seperate table but the order is not coming out in the right order.

Could anyone point out where this is going wrong please?

Table `CompetitionEntries` (Not used in query but maybe relevant)

```
id | PhotoTitle
=======================
23 |   'Photo 1'
24 |   'Photo 2'
25 |   'Photo 3'
26 |   'Photo 4'
=======================
```

Table `CompetitionVotes`

```
id | IdOfPhotoVotedOn
=======================
10 |   23
11 |   24
12 |   22
13 |   22
14 |   22
15 |   24
=======================
```

I am trying to use the statement shown below"

```
SELECT `IdOfPhotoVotedOn`, COUNT(`IdOfPhotoVotedOn`) 'Votes' 
FROM `CompetitionVotes` 
WHERE 1
GROUP BY `IdOfPhotoVotedOn`
ORDER BY 'Votes' DESC, `IdOfPhotoVotedOn`
```

What I am getting is

```
IdOfPhotoVotedOn | Votes
==========================
   22            |   3
   23            |   1
   24            |   2
```

I am trying to get is

```
IdOfPhotoVotedOn | Votes
==========================
   22            |   3
   24            |   2
   23            |   1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this?

```
SELECT `IdOfPhotoVotedOn`, COUNT(`IdOfPhotoVotedOn`) 'Votes' 
FROM `CompetitionVotes` 
WHERE 1
GROUP BY `IdOfPhotoVotedOn`
ORDER BY COUNT(`IdOfPhotoVotedOn`) DESC, `IdOfPhotoVotedOn`
```

Comment: Spot on thanks Dems. Will tick/vote when 5 minutes has passed.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT `IdOfPhotoVotedOn`, COUNT(`IdOfPhotoVotedOn`) 'Votes' 
FROM `CompetitionVotes` 
WHERE 1
GROUP BY `IdOfPhotoVotedOn`) A
ORDER BY A.Votes DESC;
```